# How do I change matlab colorbar scaling

Tags: matlab, colorbar, colormap

I am having a really hard time understanding how to change the range of my colorbar in Matlab2015b.

By default it will range from 0 to 1. I managed to change the label by using:

```matlab
    c=colorbar;
    c.Limits=[0 180] % the range that I want
```

The problem is the colors don't scale when I do that, in other words it will display from 0 to 180 but still uses the colors associated to [0 1], which makes look the the whole bar like one color.

[image]

I used another approach by just changing the ticks and doing:

`colorbar('Yticks',[0:10:180])`.

Again, the colorbar is still associated to 0 to 1, so none of the ticks except 0 will appear as the first one starts at 10.

[image]

How do I change the data it is based on ? I tried changing `c.UserData` but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Could you post a sample of your code? I cannot reproduce this problem. My colorbar automatically uses the data range.

Comment: Sure,
In this case I am really using the colorbar separately from the plot itself, it's not like I am plotting a surface and adding the colorbar to it. I am plotting a series of curves and I would like to use a colorbar instead of a legend (as there are many curves and it would look nicer this way).

h=loglog(fliplr(PeTotal)/1e6,zTab/1000); %set of curves that I am plotting

colorCode=jet(length(chiTab));

for k=1:length(chiTab) %length(chiTab) is just the number of curves

set(h(k),'Color',colorCode(k,:));

end

colormap(colorCode);

colorbar;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment, I see what you are trying to do.

You are on the right lines setting `ytick`, but as you noticed this only changes the position of the ticks on your colorbar, but the scaling stays the same. Instead, try to set `yticklabel`:

```
% Show the colorbar
c = colorbar;

% Define the desired ticks
ticks = [0:10:180];

% Sets the correct location and number of ticks
set(c, 'ytick', ticks / max(ticks));

% Set the tick labels as desired
set(c, 'yticklabel', ticks);
```

Answer (score 1):

A way that does not manually override tick specification can be achieved by:

```matlab
limits = [0,180];
c = colorbar;
set(gca,'clim',limits([1,end]))
```

From there, the ticks may be manually changed or left alone as desired.

1. Original scale colorbar
2. Rescaled, but retained auto-tick labels

[image]
[image]